# If condition in @Html.DisplayFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to display different messages based on data from statusid table. Let say for example if my statusid is 1120 then i would like to display "PASS" but i am struggling with the correct syntax.

If statusid=1120 then "PASS".

Here is my code for displaying statusid:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.statusid)
```

Any idea?

Comment: if you look at what is generated in a display for there are no tags.  It is just the value.  If you are looking for something on the fly then just use jquery to set the value

Comment: Have you tried using an Enum? You may need a custom `HtmlHelper` to use an Enum, I can't quite recall.

Comment: what would you like to display if it is not 1120.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make an object with all the properties you need

```
SomeObject.statusId
SomeObject.message

@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SomeObjectInstance)
```

Doing it this way let's you add the code and logic outside the view, which is generally recommended.

Answer (score 5):

If you only have a few values from statusid then you can do this.

```
@if (@Model.statusid == 1120)
            {
                <span>PASS</span>
            }
            else
            {
                <span>FAIL</span>
            }
```